# OOP Java : can return an child class to parent class?

Tags: java, oop, extends

I'm a newcomer of OOP, so I has one silly question about when a class `extends` another class.

Here my example:

```
public class Test {
    public Monitor getMonitor(){
        return new LCD();
    }

    class LCD extends Monitor {   NO-ERROR
    class LCD {                   ERROR at line `return new LCD` 
        //some other method or function not in Monitor Class. Example:
        boolean isSamsung;
        public LCD whatkindLCD(){           
        }       
    }
}
```

I have one question for above code : because `LCD` is extended from `Monitor` and `LCD` has some other properties/methods that Monitor does not. So, `LCD` is child of `Monitor`, right ?

It means you try to put a "big box" to a "small box".  So, why when I `return new LCD`, Eclipse don't notice error as when I just use `class LCD {`.

Thanks :)

Comment: No, try casting when you get the Monitor back.

Comment: @TedHopp In Eclipse, it will notice: `cannot convert from LCD to Monitor class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand Inheritance as a "is a" relationship. Here is a simple example I used to understand inheritance during my novice years.

```
class Employee
{
    String name;
    int salary;

    Employee()
    {
        name = "Employee";
        salary = 5000;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public int getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }
}
class Manager extends Employee
{
    int bonus;
    int salary;

    Manager()
    {
        bonus = 1000;
        salary = 6000;
    }
    public int getBonus()
    {
        return bonus;
    }
    public int getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }   
}

class Test
{        
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Employee e = new Employee();
        System.out.println(e.getName());
        //System.out.println(e.getBonus());
        System.out.println(e.getSalary());

        System.out.println();

        Manager m = new Manager();
        System.out.println(m.getName());
        System.out.println(m.getBonus());
        System.out.println(m.getSalary());

        System.out.println();

        Employee em = new Manager();
        System.out.println(em.getName());                   
        //System.out.println(em.getBonus());            
        System.out.println(((Manager)em).getBonus());
        System.out.println(em.getSalary());     
        }
}
```

Compiler looks for reference type before calling any operations on it.
em.getBonus() doesn't work because Employee doesn't have a bonus method.
But using a cast we can make it work.
((Manager)em.)getBonus()

Reason why compiler looks for the reference type before calling any operation on it is as follows:

Manager[] managers = new Manager[10];

It is legal to convert this array to an Employee[] array:

Employee[] staff = managers; // OK

Sure, why not, you may think. After all, if manager[i] is a Manager, it is also an Employee. But actually, something surprising is going on. Keep in mind that managers and staff are references to the same array.

Now consider the statement

staff[0] = new Employee("John Eipe", ...);

The compiler will cheerfully allow this assignment. 
But staff[0] and manager[0] are the same reference, so it looks as if we managed to smuggle a mere employee into the management 
ranks.

That would be very bad — calling managers[0].setBonus(1000) would try to access a 
nonexistent instance field and would corrupt neighboring memory. 
To make sure no such corruption can occur, all arrays remember the element type with 
which they were created, and they monitor that only compatible references are stored into 
them. For example, the array created as new Manager[10] remembers that it is an array of 
managers. Attempting to store an Employee reference causes an ArrayStoreException.

Comment: Very clear example and explaination. As you say, that `during novice year` :D So, as your example, I understand that: when you call someone is an employee, (but it actual is a manager), Compiler will prevent you act employee as a manager, except you `typecast`: "this employee must be a manager, right :D

Answer (score 5):

In your second (error) case, you've forgotten to declare that `LCD` does in fact extend `Monitor`.  You're just defining a "normal", standalone class - and so a `new LCD()` is *not* an instance of `Monitor`.

The compiler should be happy if you declare the `LCD` class like this:

```
class LCD extends Monitor {
    //some other method or function not in Monitor Class. Example:
    boolean isSamsung;
    public LCD whatkindLCD(){           
    }       
}
```

---

**Edit** (in response to comment):  It's not a problem at all that the `LCD` class has extra properties/methods compared to `Monitor`.  The code that's going to call `getMonitor()`, only really cares that it gets a `Monitor` back - that is, something that has all the methods and properties and behaviour of a `Monitor`.

So if you had `turnOff` and `displayBitmap(int[][] data)` methods on your `Monitor` class, then your `LCD` class will also have these methods.  Any instance of `LCD` can behave as a `Monitor` when one is needed - this is the basic principle of subclassing in OO languages.  So whenever something wants a `Monitor`, you can give it an `LCD`, or an instance of `CRT` or `SamsungLCD` instead if you had those, and the compiler can be satisfied that the right methods/properties will exist and can be called.

(Technically this is the [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) if you like formal definitions, but you don't need to understand it in that level of detail.)

Comment: Yes. I know why `class LCD` will be wrong. The thing I don't know is : why can assign `LCD` as `Monitor`, because `LCD` has some properties that `Monitor` don't

Comment: Oh. thank for your link give me. I cannot imagine this simple thinking has a principle behind. So interesting !

Answer (score 3):

The box analogy is wrong, think of an `is a` relationship instead.

In the first example, `LCD extends Monitor`, that is `LCD is a Monitor`, therefore anywhere where Monitor is expected, LCD is fine. When you think about in real-world terms instead of looking at the code, you realise this is correct. Everything that you can expect a monitor in general to do (e.g. display a picture), an LCD monitor will do.

In the second example LCD is not a Monitor, so you get an error message.

Comment: As I say to Doyle I just don't know is : why can assign `LCD` as `Monitor`, because `LCD` has some properties that `Monitor` don't.  In normal life, you can say `LCD` is a `Monitor`. But I cannot imagine, why can you use `Monitor` variable like `LCD` variable ?

Comment: Yes, but those properties don't matter. If someone asks for a glass of water, they usually don't care if the glass is made of plastic, glass or metal, whether it has a handle or not, or indeed if it's a mug, what kind of decoration, if any it has. No, the only thing important is that it can hold water and that water can be drunk from it. The same is true here: by defining your method to return  a `Monitor` type, you declare that you're simply not interested in any additional properties it might have.

Comment: Ah. thanks you. So, you mean, when someone ask : "Give me a glass of water". And you can give him a metal glass or plastic glass, right ?

Comment: and, as you say that `not interested in any additional properties it might have`. So, information special about `LCD` will be lost ? That means when you use that `Monitor` object and call like: `monitor.whatkindLCD()` will be notice error ?

Comment: @hqt Yes, but the exact type information will not be lost, just not visible. Later you'll come across examples where this information is recovered. (For example when you want to put the empty glass in the dishwasher, the material it's made of suddenly starts to matter.)

Answer (score 0):

Your method `getMonitor` returns a "Monitor" type.

When you extend your class LCD with Monitor, you are saying the complier that LCD **is a** Monitor.
When you remove the **extends**, the LCD class becomes a plain class and not a Monitor type.
If you modify your getMonitor to

```
public LCD getMonitor(){
       // code here
}
```

The error will go.